# How to achieve thread-safety in my code

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

Let's say I have a class **Base** with a single member ***message*** (String). Another class **BaseHandler** which extends this **Base** class. In this handler I have a method ***print*** which is setting a value to the base and printing it. At the end of call to print, I am setting the message to null. 
When I create 50000 threads and run handler's print method, I get null pointer exception once in a while.

Questions:
Why is null pointer exception thrown when I am explicitly assigning the value? 
How would each threads instantiate the Base in this case?
Would the solution be marking Base.message as volatile and removing the null assignment? (in other words how to achieve thread-safety on ***Base.message***

Please take a look at code below:

```
public class Base {
     public String message;
 }

public class BaseHandler extends Base{

    protected static final Object lock = new Object();

    public void printMessage( ){

        synchronized ( lock ) { //This block is thread safe
            System.out.println( message.toUpperCase( ) );
            message = null;
        }
    }

}

public class Test {   
    public static void main(String[] args){       
        final BaseHandler handler = new BaseHandler();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            Runnable task = new Runnable(){
                @Override 
                public void run( ) {
                    handler.message = "Hello world! ";
                    handler.printMessage( );
                }                
            };
            Thread worker = new Thread(task);
            worker.setName(String.valueOf(i));
            worker.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is null pointer exception thrown when I am explicitly assigning the value?

Imagine the following execution:

- Thread1: `handler.message = "Hello world! ";`
- Thread2: `handler.message = "Hello world! ";`
- Thread1: gets the lock, prints and sets message to null
- thread2: gets the lock, tries to print but `message.toUpperCase()` throws a NPE.

Your problem is that the 2 lines below are not atomic:

```
handler.message = "Hello world! ";
handler.printMessage();
```

**Solutions**

There are several alternatives, depending on what you are trying to achieve:

- you could put those 2 lines in a `synchronized(lock)` block to make the 2 calls atomic
- you could pass a parameter to the printMessage method: `printMessage(message)`, removing the shared variable issue
- you could create an instance of the class per call, removing the shared variable issue as well
- ...

Comment: Do you mean thread-safety at Base.message right? How do I achieve it?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, my question was when setting a value to the Base.message this setter should be locked with the same lock used in the BaseHandler when locking the printMessage correct?

Comment: @Mayumi No, that would still not be sufficient. You need to have something like `synchronized(lock) {handler.message="..."; handler.printMessage();}`. In other words you need to hold the lock over the whole block, you can't just lock within each method.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
handler.message = "Hello world! ";
handler.printMessage( );
```

These two operations aren't atomic, only `printMessage()` is. So this is what happens occasionally:

1. Thread A modifies `message` field
2. Thread B kicks in and modifies it as well
3. Thread B continue to operate, calling `printMessage()`
4. `printMessage()` in thread B finishes and cleans up `message` field
5. Thread A is restored and calls `printMessage()`. Disaster happens

If you want your code to be thread safe, these two operations need to be atomic. Hard to advice something because there are several other issues in your code: public mutable field, visibility problem, lock is unnecessarily static...

If you can modify this pseudo-code, I would simply pass `message` as an argument of `printMessage()` (sound reasonable) and forget about thread-safety and multi-threading. The code would be safe.

Comment: I agree. Will instantiate Base instead of extending it.

Answer (score 1):

You are locking on a read, but you need to lock on when you update the value. Your lock needs to encompass both in order to achieve thread safety: i.e. lock on these.

```
handler.message = "Hello world! ";
handler.printMessage( );
```

Answer (score 1):

The **setting of message, is not thread-safe in your code...**

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable{

BaseHandler handler = new BaseHandler();

public synchronized void go(){

          for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {

                    handler.message = "Hello world! ";
                    handler.printMessage( );
                }                




   }

}
```

**Now Let you Base and BaseHandler as it is...
With few changes to Test class**

```
public class Test {   
    public static void main(String[] args){       


            Thread worker = new Thread(MyClass);
            worker.setName(String.valueOf(i));
            worker.start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure thread-safety both for the read and for the write operations on the shared mutable object. In your case, you are doing an unsafe write. Also, the read and the write need to share the same lock.

```
public synchronized void setMessage(String msg) {
        this.message = msg;
    }

    public synchronized String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Note that here I'm implicitly using the object instance as lock. It's a common mistake to use different objects as lock for the same mutable object.

Then, your BaseHandler class will look something like this:

```
public class BaseHandler extends Base {

    public synchronized void printMessage( ) {
        if (getMessage()!=null) {
            System.out.println( getMessage().toUpperCase( ) );
            setMessage(null);
        }
    }
}
```

These two methods makes your Base-BaseHandler class hierarchy thread-safe to any client.
That means that clients using your object do not need to use synchronization.

Comment: That does not solve the issue. The call to your `setMessage` method and the `printMessage` method will still need to be atomic to avoid the NPE.

Comment: @assylias Yes, exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: What I understand from your post is: make sure you use a lock in both the `setMessage` and `printMessage` methods and make sure you use the same lock in both. I am saying this is not enough. But I might have misunderstood your point.

Comment: @assylias I see you have a point. But your proposal does not make BaseHandler thread safe, it only "deals" with BaseHandler being unsafe. The right approach would be to check if (message!=null) before the operation.

Comment: One of my proposals is to use client side locking *because* the class is not thread safe. I agree that the design you propose makes the class thread safe, but it does not address the issue and will still cause random NPE errors. As for checking if message is null, that would avoid the NPE error, but some messages might get lost while some might get printed twice...

Comment: I have removed my downvote but my last point still stands: some messages might get lost and some messages might get printed twice because there is no atomicity between setMessage and printMessage calls.

Comment: @assylias Corrected my answer. I guess the goal of this question is to learn about concurrency, so making an object thread-safe would be my first option. Locking at the client-side can lead to deadlock if the locks are not taken in the right order.

Comment: @assylias in light of learning thread-safety, the difference between locking the accessors and making the two operations an atomic block is that of concurrency. Enclosing the two operations in an atomic block effectively serializes execution, so it would be better to have it running in 1 thread as there's no parallelization possible.  Making the object calls thread-safe increases parallelism, but introduces potential data loss. This is of course due to the contrieved nature of the example.

Answer (score 1):

You are using fragile extension and shared mutable state to achieve what would be much simpler if you just passed the state around on the stack as parameters. Make printMessage take the message as a parameter and you solve all these problems.

```
public void printMessage(final String message){
    System.out.println( message.toUpperCase( ) );
}
```

Now you only need to deal with the case where you were *actually* passed a null.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's exactly what I ended up doing. No idea why I extended the class that holds args....